# Swagger definition for firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, jwt, swagger

Could anyone provide a working sample of a Swagger security definition for firebase authentication?

On the backend, firebase ID token is verified using the firebase admin SDK:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);
```

What should be the values in the Swagger security definition to get the proper ID token for firebase?

```json
"securityDefinitions": {
        "firebase": {
            "authorizationUrl": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth",
            "flow": "implicit",
            "type": "oauth2",
            "x-google-issuer": "https://securetoken.google.com/MY-PROJECT-ID",
            "x-google-jwks_uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com",
            "x-google-audiences": "MY-CLIENT-ID",
            "scopes": {
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase": "Firebase scope"
            }
        }
    }
```

I do get a token back, however, firebase admin SDK says it's not valid:

> Decoding Firebase ID token failed. Make sure you passed the entire
> string JWT which represents an ID token

Not sure if this is because of the wrong scopes or token types...

Comment: Your configuration seems ok, do you use the user.getIdToken() method  to get the firebase token which is different from the classic google Oauth token ?

Answer (score 2):

Using Firebase to authenticate users / [Configuring your OpenAPI document](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users-firebase) explains it.
The given example definitely does not have any `authorizationUrl` or `scopes` section:

```
securityDefinitions:
  firebase:
    authorizationUrl: ""
    flow: "implicit"
    type: "oauth2"
    # Replace YOUR-PROJECT-ID with your project ID
    x-google-issuer: "https://securetoken.google.com/YOUR-PROJECT-ID"
    x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com"
    x-google-audiences: "YOUR-PROJECT-ID"
```

And this `firebase` security definition also needs to be added into the `security` section, at either the API or method level:

```
security:
  - firebase: []
```

---

It might help to read [troubleshooting JWT validation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/troubleshoot-jwt).

Answer (score 1):

i am putting this here just for reference

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/pull/7699

I've started a PR that will enable login/popup that swagger uses

to be plugged in with a custom extension that does `firebase` specific logic

Comment: looks like this is merge. I'm serving swagger-via `swagger-ui-express` middleware. Is there a way to integrate it with Firebase Auth?